# Is there any library for performing an automated reasoning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, discrete-mathematics

I want to write a program that can do a deductive reasoning like that:

Premises:

1.All cats are birds.

2.Every bird can fly.

Conclusion:
Every cat can fly. (It's nonsense though)

(It's just an example. Actually it would be more complex than this)

The program I desire will be able to receive a conclusion input by user and check whether it is valid under given premises that's already stored within the program and, if possible, able to suggest what conclusion would be valid.

So, my question, is there any library that can work in that way for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention a language, so I don't know if what you really want is a library. What you describe sounds like *automated theorem proving* and so you might do well to investigate that topic. One automated theorem proving language - or interactive proof assistant, or whatever you like - is Coq. I have not used it but the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) page is informative. I tried to put together a simple proof but frankly it's a little complicated.

Another option is logic programming. PROLOG, for instance, would let you do something like:

```
canfly(X) :- isbird(X).
isbird(X) :- iscat(X).
iscat(tom).
?- canfly(tom).
Yes
```

Comment: Since this is a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), it could also be solved by an SMT solver such as [Z3](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial).